# javascript validate swedish birthnumber

Tags: javascript, validation

im trying to do a simple validation for an input who shall allow a number formated like this: 112233-1111 and when i accomplish that i would make it so that 22 cant exceed 12 and 33 exceed 31, this is what i got so far

```
var pn=document.forms.kontakt.pnr.value;
var spos=pn.indexOf("-"); 
var as= /^[0-9]{10}$/; 
if (pn<11 || spos+4=pn.length || pn==null || pn=="")
{
alert ("Fyll i korrekt personnummer xxxxxx-xxxx");
kontakt.pnr.style.background = "red";
return false;   
}
```

but it aint working, have i missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here that I'd like to point out. First, `spos+4=pn.length` should be `spos+4==pn.length` (double equals because you are comparing). `x` does not seem to be defined and should be removed. Your regex variable `as` is never used.

Really, what you want to do is:

```js
function calculate() {
  //this matches 6 numbers followed by a ("-" or "+") followed by 4 more numbers
  var as = /^[0-9]{6}[-+][0-9]{4}$/;
  var pn=document.forms.kontakt.pnr.value;
  if (as.test(pn)) {
    var year = pn.substr(0,2);
    var month = pn.substr(2,2);
    var day = pn.substr(4,2);
    //You probably need a better date checker, this is just an example
    if (month <= 12 && day <= 30) {
      document.body.innerHTML = 'great success!';
      return;
    }
  }
  document.body.innerHTML = 'Too bad!';
}
```

```html
<form name="kontakt">
  <input name="pnr" type="text" value="991222-1111"/>
  <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: ok thanks! but if i type something that doesnt fit the pattern that script dont post "too bad!"

Comment: Give me an example, please.

Comment: yes, however im having abit of trouble modifying it so that if more then 12 and 30 it will post error, trying to learn this, started like 2 days ago haha, any pointers?

Comment: im trying to do it this way, this is just experimental for me cuz i want to     learn javascript.                                                                                                                   var as = /^[0-9]{6}[-+][0-9]{4}$/;
         var pn=document.forms.kontakt.pnr.value;
      if (as.test(pn)) {
      var year = pn.substr(0,2);
      var month = pn.substr(2,2);
      var day = pn.substr(4,2);
      if (month >= 12 || day >= 30)

      {
     alert ("Fyll i korrekt personnummer xxxxxx-xxxx");
     kontakt.pnr.style.background = "red";
     return false;
     }
     }